# Disable a button while a DomainContext IsLoading

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, domaindatasource

I have a button on a form which I want to be disabled as long as my DomainDataSource's **DataContext.IsLoading** is **true**; I want to bind the **IsEnabled** property of the button to a ! condition on **DomainContext.IsLoading** and unfortunately I do not know how to handle it as a conditional expression. I can get it working in the reverse of my intended fashion, but not the way I want it to be.

My question is, how do I make this:

```
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=someDomainDataSource, Path=DomainContext.IsLoading}" />
```

effectively be a ! condition along the lines of (this of course does not work) this:

```
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=someDomainDataSource, Path=!DomainContext.IsLoading}" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a ValueConverter for this, something like an `BooleanInverter` which on conversion, inverts the value.  See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Your binding would then be

```
 <Button IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=someDomainDataSource, Path=DomainContext.IsLoading, Converter={StaticResource BooleanInverter}}" />
```